# Unable to open log4j compressed files using winzip

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

After referring to posts here, I was able to successfully configure to use log4j extras jar and create a compressed log file. However, when i open the compressed file, it throws an error indicating that its a invalid zip file. Below is my log4j configuration. As you can see I am trying to create one log file every minute and have it compressed. Am I doing something wrong in this configuration file? Please advice.

```
<appender name="EventLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <param name="ActiveFileName" value="C:/EventLogs/log" />
    <param name="FileNamePattern" value="C:/EventLogs/log%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.zip" />
</rollingPolicy>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}\t%m%n" />
</layout>
</appender>
```

EDIT: Found that the file can be opened / extracted using winrar but not winzip

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the same root cause, but mine was similar - my files were being rolled as per my TimeBasedRollingPolicy but when I tried to open them, I received errors that they were invalid zip files.

Turns out that they were not zipped at all. The files had been renamed as *.zip as per the FileNamePattern, but compression was not occurring.

In the log4j source code TimeBasedRollingPolicy.java, we see:

...

```
if (lastFileName.endsWith(".gz")) {
  suffixLength = 3;
} else if (lastFileName.endsWith(".zip")) {
  suffixLength = 4;
}
```

...

```
if (suffixLength == 4) {
    compressAction =
    new ZipCompressAction(
      new File(lastBaseName), new File(lastFileName), true);
}
```

...

My log4j.properties file had trailing spaces after the .zip in my FileNamePattern, so the length was neither 3 or 4.

My suggestions for the log4j extras team would be:

- use trim() on the file name
- don't rename to e.g. zip unless compression actually occurs

Comment: Interesting one. The file that was created in my case was already compressed. Well, as you said the root cause is not similar but this is something to watch out for.